# Meaning of "have got it to"

Tags: word-usage, idioms

What does `have got it to` mean in this sentence:

> I've got it to work in the emulator running Q image

I know that we use `have got to` when we are saying that something is necessary. But I don't understand how it is applied to the above sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is different because of the use of the pronoun *it*.

---

> 1. I have got to work.

This mean that you must perform some kind of job or activity.

It's actually more common to leave out the *got*:

> I have to work. OR
>   I must work.

---

> 2. I have *got* ***it*** to work.

This means that you managed to get something else to perform some task:

> I managed to make it function (operate).

In this case, it's more common to leave out the *have*:

> I got it to work.

So:

> The machine was broken, but I got it to work after taking a look at an instruction manual.

---

In summary:

> I have to work. <sup>(I have got to work.)</sup>
>   → I must do some job.
>
> I got **it** to work. <sup>(I have got it to work.)</sup>
>   → I figured out how to make it do its job.

---

Note that there is another possible interpretation.

> I (have) got it to work.
>   → I have taken it to work.

In other words, *got*, in this context, can be synonymous with *took*.

You can only really know which of the two interpretations is meant from context.

---

This follows something similar with the sentence without the pronoun. Perhaps annoyingly, it can have two interpretations:

> I got to work.
>   → 1. I started working.
>   → 2. I arrived at work.

As with *I got it to work*, you can only tell which interpretation is meant from context.